# How can I find .git repositories and pull'em all?

Tags: find, cygwin

I tried.

```
$ find . -name .git -type d -execdir git pull {};
find: The relative path ‘%ANDROID_HOME%/tools’ is
included in the PATH environment variable,
which is insecure in combination with the
-execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: 1. You should use `'*.git'` with `-iname`. 2. Your PATH shouldn't have `%ANDROID_HOME%` - that's a Windows variable.

Comment: @muru Sorry, `cygwin` tag added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `;` with `+` at the end.

From the manpage:

> ```
>    -execdir command {} +
>           Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory  containing
>           the  matched  file,  which  is not normally the directory in which you started
>           find.  This a much more secure method for invoking commands, as it avoids race
>           conditions  during  resolution of the paths to the matched files.  As with the
>           -exec action, the `+' form of -execdir will build a command  line  to  process
>           more than one matched file, but any given invocation of command will only list
>           files that exist in the same subdirectory.  If you use this option,  you  must
>           ensure that your $PATH environment variable does not reference `.'; otherwise,
>           an attacker can run any commands they like by leaving  an  appropriately-named
>           file  in a directory in which you will run -execdir.  The same applies to hav‐
>           ing entries in $PATH which are empty  or  which  are  not  absolute  directory
>           names.   If  find  encounters  an error, this can sometimes cause an immediate
>           exit, so some pending commands may not be run at all.
> ```